# I cant Add the Sum of two numbers to the next inputted amount

Tags: html, angular

Value 1 here has an amount of 10000, then I got the result in Value2 total of 8500, in Value3 I will  input an a desired amount then Add it to the Value2.Ex: 1000 + 8500. So what happened to me is I cant add Value3 + Value2 = Value4. I hope someone could help me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sum-ef7c94?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

.html

```
<input style="width:300px" type="number"  (keypress)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)" 
[readonly]="true" [(ngModel)]="value1">

<input style="width:300px" type="number"  (keypress)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)" 
[readonly]="true" [(ngModel)]="value2" value = "{{myMath.abs(value1 * 0.15 - value1)}}">

<input style="width:300px" type="number"  (keypress)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)" 
[readonly]="true" [(ngModel)]="value3" >

<input style="width:300px" type="number"  (keypress)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)" 
[readonly]="true" [(ngModel)]="value4" value = "{{myMath.abs(value3 + value2)}}">
```

Comment: Also, share the .ts file so that we can see what you are doing in code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  value1: number = 10000;
  value2: number = Math.abs(this.value1 * 0.15 - this.value1);
  value3: number = 0;
  value4: number = Math.abs(this.value2 + this.value3);

  public myMath = Math;

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="FirstNumber"
      [(ngModel)]="value1"
    /><br />

    Total<input
      value="{{ myMath.abs(value1 * 0.15 - value1) }}"
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Total"
      [(ngModel)]="value2"
    /><br />

    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Input an Amount"
      [(ngModel)]="value3"
    />

    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder=""
      [(ngModel)]="value4"
      value="{{ myMath.abs(value2 + value3) }}"
    />
  </div>
</div>

Now you know how to add the 8500 to the Input amount ex: 1000 + 8500
```

Or check this snippet:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sum-sqe2kv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thank you so much Eugene! I can now add it to the input amount

Comment: May I ask a question, What If the value1: number = 10000 is not set like that, umh The value1 will be randomly supplied that is came from the database.


value1 (is waiting for the patchvalue that will be selected)

value 2 = (value1 * 0.15 - value1)
value 3 = inputted
value 4 = (value2 + value3)

Comment: i'm getting an error on this.value1 and his.value1). because I did not set value 1 as number = 1000.

Comment: @ThomasGreene hope it helps: 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/sum-sqe2kv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts